# Getting Location of Created Object from AspNet WebApi with HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I got an Service to Post Data and Returning Location of Created Object

```
 public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]ErbrachteLeistung value)
{
  int newLeistungId = service.AddErbrachteLeistung(value);
  return Created($"api/ErbrachteLeistung/{newLeistungId}", value);
}
```

My Client Looks like this

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
  {
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    AllowAutoRedirect = true
  };

  using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
  {
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(WebApiUri);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync<ErbrachteLeistung>("api/ErbrachteLeistung", erbrachteLeistung).Result;
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  }
```

How can I read the Created Location given in the WebService out of the Response?

Answer (score 0):

The 201 Created response stores that value in the Location Header

```
//...
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Uri location = response.Headers.Location;

//...
```